# Could not load file or assembly (SSIS)

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-assembly

I am working with

- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
- Installed extension SQL Server Integration Services Projects
- 64 Bit System

With a simple sample code from microsoft, I am getting an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."
```

I don't understand this, because I added the reference to that assembly. On my system it resides here:

```
 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you search RegEdit to the object?  VS is searching the registry to find the dll.  It may not be registered or different version.

Comment: I found an entry in the registry here: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{120FF0BE-9510-4B5E-9FDE-2535D71943DD}\InprocServer32\10.0.0.0

Comment: That is InprocServer32 and not Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap